# How to Quickly Open a <header> File in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, ide, visual-studio-2013, header-files

Is there a way to quickly open a `<header>` file in VS2013, e.g. from **QuickLaunch**?

If the `<header>` is already #included in the code in the editor, I can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, or right-click on the `<header>` (in the `#include <header>` line) and chose *Open document `<header>`*.

e.g.

[image: Open document example]

But if the `<header>` is *not* in the list of `#include`s, is there a way to *quickly* open it (instead of doing `File -> Open...` and then navigate inside Visual Studio installation path, then find the `VC` folder, then `include` subfolder, etc.)?

Comment: No, there's no command for this, the editor implements it.

Comment: @HansPassant: If you are sure about that, you may want to write a reply, so I can mark it as answer (and close the question).

Comment: SO users only like happy answers.  I've had enough downvotes on "you can't do that" answers to last me a while.

Comment: @HansPassant: I just like honest true answers :) , even if that means "you can't do that". And I think it's better to give you the credit, than writing a reply myself based on your comment, and mark my own "pseudo reply" as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Navigate To...` text box to search for the header.

The keyboard shortcut is:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>